# Update column based on most recent date time

Tags: sql

I have a statement that I want to UPDATE a row's `ColumnA` if `ColumnB` meets the LIKE query and `ColumnC` is the most recent date.

My `ColumnC` is a `DateTime` column and at the moment the statement ignores the request for most recent DateTime and updates all records with ColumnB.

Here it is

```
"UPDATE table1 SET ColumnA= '" + data +
"' WHERE ColumnB LIKE '" + variable +
"' AND MAX(ColumnC);";
```

Comment: What is your DBMS?  Please add the appropriate tags, and also, don't use irrelevant tags (I've removed your c# tag).

Comment: You should use SQL parameters instead of concatenating strings to prevent SQL injection, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Comment: Thanks for the help with tags, that's my bad! I'm aware of the sql injection, the system I'm building won't be available online. I'm building something that will be used within a company, and am not to worried about SQL injection. Should I be?

Comment: @MitchelStuartFountaine http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: That's hilarious. I'm scared now, thanks! Will make changes. Testing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
AND MAX(ColumnC);
```

is not valid any DBMS as far as I know. Probably you looking to filter your `ColumnC` with maximum value of it with the same condition.

Pseudo code:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET ColumnA = data
WHERE ColumnB LIKE variable 
AND ColumnC = (SELECT MAX(ColumnC) from table1 WHERE ColumnB LIKE variable)
```

Also you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) when you build your queries. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Thanks Soner, that works a charm! I noticed others "Nesting" statements. I clearly understand how it works now. My only observation is your answer is missing a parenthisis. Thanks for the help!